# How to add all list of values to mysql database and keep adding even if there are duplicate primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

In my server I'm adding values to database using a command like

```
INSERT INTO votes VALUES ('1',0),('2',0),('3',0)
```

The primary key is the first argument of each value key. Sometimes, when adding, the primary key may already exist in the table.

The issue is that, if that happens, I get an error, and it stops the whole process of adding them all.

Is there a way such that, if the current key already exists, then it just skips the current value set, and moves on to the next one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT IGNORE INTO votes VALUES ('1',0),('2',0),('3',0);`

Answer (score 1):

No need to explicitly assign primary key if the primary key is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Assuming your table `votes` has 2 columns: `id` and `data`:

The query is:

```
INSERT INTO votes (`data`) VALUES (0),(0),(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `INSERT IGNORE` syntax, it will work